# turn a web page into an image with ColdFusion, Java or command line utility?

Tags: java, coldfusion

Native ancient solution in ColdFusion that used to work with HTML 3.x...

```
<cfhttp url="#targetUrl#" resolveurl="yes"> 

<cfdocument format="pdf" name="pdfVar">
    #cfhttp.filecontent# 
</cfdocument> 

<cfpdf action="thumbnail" source="#pdfVar#" pages="1" destination="image">
<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#image#">
```

Super slow, even with cache, many CSS styles missing or broken.

Any good server-side solution to capture a rendered webpage into a thumbnail?  like service provided by http://www.shrinktheweb.com/ ?

Any ColdFusion, Java or Command line utility solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an Image with ColdFusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490094/creating-an-image-with-coldfusion)

Comment: I gave an answer on that thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490094/creating-an-image-with-coldfusion/7492891#7492891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using SiteShoter which uses IE as the renderering engine.  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_site_screenshot.html

Answer (score 1):

This website has a script that does what I think your looking for, I haven’t tried using it for any server-side project though.

http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/

Doesn’t make thumbnails though, but you could render the image created with cfimage.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ColdFusion version 8 or better, you can simply [use CFDOCUMENT to create a thumbnail](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/6/13/ColdFusion-8-URL-Thumbnails).

From Ray's post:

```
<cfdocument src="http://www.coldfusionjedi.com" name="pdfdata" format="pdf" />
<cfpdf source="pdfdata" pages="1" action="thumbnail" destination="." format="jpg" overwrite="true" resolution="high" scale="25">
```

Comment: still, cfdocument's engine supports very little CSS... and it's slow, and I bet it's doing about the same things as my code