# Generating an image from HTML with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, jpeg, coldfusion-9

I have a ColdFusion page with a styled HTML table in it. What I would like to be able to do is set up a feature that allows our customers to save the table as an image file, for use in their slide shows. I have read some of the documentation for cfcontent however, I am beginning to get the feeling that I will need a third party library. I was hoping someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: I wish I can help, but I have the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341782/turn-a-web-page-into-an-image-with-coldfusion-java-or-command-line-utility

Comment: Hmmm, I wish I would have found your post earlier =|, anyway I'll let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could render your html table to a static page, then call http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ using cfexecute to render to pdf, or wkhtmltoimage can convert to .png .gif etc

Here's a static page with a test table and some css table.cfm

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table test</title>

</head>
<style>
 *{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
 }
 body{
     font-family: Georgia, serif;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-style: italic;
     font-weight: normal;
     letter-spacing: normal;
 }
 #content{
     padding:40px;
     margin:0 auto;
     -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 16px #aaa;
 }

/* Table 1 Style */
table.table1{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-style: normal;
    border-collapse:separate;
}
.table1 thead th{
    padding:15px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #568F23;
    border:1px solid #93CE37;
    border-bottom:3px solid #9ED929;
    background-color:#9DD929;
    background:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.02, rgb(123,192,67)),
        color-stop(0.51, rgb(139,198,66)),
        color-stop(0.87, rgb(158,217,41))
        );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(123,192,67) 2%,
        rgb(139,198,66) 51%,
        rgb(158,217,41) 87%
        );
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
.table1 thead th:empty{
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
}
.table1 tbody th{
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #568F23;
    background-color:#9DD929;
    border:1px solid #93CE37;
    border-right:3px solid #9ED929;
    padding:0px 10px;
    background:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.02, rgb(158,217,41)),
        color-stop(0.51, rgb(139,198,66)),
        color-stop(0.87, rgb(123,192,67))
        );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        left bottom,
        rgb(158,217,41) 2%,
        rgb(139,198,66) 51%,
        rgb(123,192,67) 87%
        );
    -moz-border-radius:5px 0px 0px 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
.table1 tfoot td{
    color: #9CD009;
    font-size:32px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #444;
}
.table1 tfoot th{
    color:#666;
}
.table1 tbody td{
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#DEF3CA;
    border: 2px solid #E7EFE0;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
    </style>
<body>
<div id="content">

<table  class="table1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>column 1</th>
    <th>column 2</th>
    <th>column 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>oranges</td>
    <td>lemons</td>
    <td>apples</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <td>red</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>green</td>
</tr>

</tfoot>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Make a simple batch file wkhtmltoimage.bat

```
f:\temp\wkhtmltoimage --crop-h 250 --crop-w 200 http://localhost:8500/table.cfm f:\temp\outputfile.png
```

More command line options [here](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html)

Use cfexecute to run the batch file

```
<cfexecute name="F:\temp\wkhtmltoimage.bat" timeout="20" variable="result"> 
</cfexecute>
```

Output is pretty nice

[image]

The windows installer [libwkhtmltox-0.10.0_rc2.zip](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=libwkhtmltox-0.10.0_rc2.zip&can=2&q=) contains topdf and wkhtmltoimage

Comment: IMGKit works under Windows?  Is that command-line or ruby lib?

Comment: Just wondering why you'd use an external program rather than CFDOCUMENT & CFPDF which are native to CF?  I'm not saying you shouldn't just wondering how this is a better solution to Henry's earlier suggestion?

Comment: Well the question asked for image output rather than pdf and lots more control over image resolution cropping size etc  the page rendering engine is WebKit so serving CSS styled tables should be pretty faithful

Answer (score 1):

check out `<cfdocument format="PDF">` and `<cfpdf action="thumbnail">`

Comment: This should get you pretty close to what you want, but the short answer is that CF does not have a feature to turn HTML into an image. If the table is small then I believe the method Henry outlines here will produce a thumbnail you're not very interested in -- it would show a lot of whitespace around the table (the table would be too small)... though it's worth a shot.

Comment: Hmmm that is what I was afraid of. Is there perhaps any third party support, that anyone knows of? I saw something on third party QR Code support for ColdFusion, and was wondering if there was something similar for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Might not be exactly what you're after but cfsilence has a post from the CF8 days that might work:

Initial Post: 
http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2008/4/4/Converting-HTML-To-An-Image-With-CFJava

Follow Up:
http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2008/4/5/More-Thoughts-on-HTML-To-Image-Plus-Code

Might get you started ... hope it's helpful!

Comment: Insightful at the least. Maybe useful to a java programmer than me.